# Ubuntu partitionation and boot does not work

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, gparted

I wanna create a second partition with gparted for my Windows but it wont work, i have a 1TB HDD and Ubuntu says that 1TB oft it is used, but only 50GB is used. So i can create an partition of 44Mib and that is not enough for Windows.

I tried it in many ways with the terminal but nothing works.

What should i do ?

And a second question is:

I cant Boot from my cd... If i Boot Form my DVD with a ISO file a purple screen appears from Ubuntu and ASK me if i wanna Start Ubuntu in different ways. What i die wrong ?

Comment: Try Ubuntu, then open a terminal, type `sudo fdisk -l` and edit your question with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu or any linux based os does not recognize unused space in the disk so to install windows insert any bootable pen devices and will installing it will show you the different partition on your disk .From there you can make a new partition and install windows in it.As per as your second question few things that I can tell is first may be your ISO image file is corrupt check its size.Second if can try to boot from a pen drive and use software develop for this by microsoft.
[use software develop for this by microsoft.](http://wudt.codeplex.com/)
on your ubuntu you can run it by using wine.

Comment: Thanks fpr your fast answer ! I deleted my hdd from the bott loader and only activated my dvdrom now i am able to boot from cd,  im now back to windows activated the hdd an will use ubuntu only in a vm.